# Why is my program creating the same linked list for every index of the array?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

The goal of this program is to create a hash table where every integer inserted is mapped to that number % 10 position within an array. For some reason, I am creating the same linked list for each index of the table. For example, the final output is currently:

0: 28 15 8 18 25

1: 28 15 8 18 25

2: 28 15 8 18 25

etc

When it should be:

0: Empty.

1: Empty.

2: Empty.

3: Empty.

4: Empty.

5: 15 25

6: Empty.

7: Empty.

8: 28 8 18

9: Empty.

Here is my code with each class separated by slashes:

```
public class myHash{
   public static LinkedList[] array = new LinkedList[10];

   public static int hash(int value){
      return value % 10;
   }

   public static void initArray(){
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         array[i] = new LinkedList();
      }
   }

   public static void insert(int value){
      int index = hash(value);
      System.out.println("Inserting " + value + " at location " + index + ".");
      LinkedList list = array[index];
      list.insertData(value);
      array[index] = list;

   }

   public static void delete(int value){
      int index = hash(value);
      LinkedList list = array[index];
      list.remove(value);
   }    


   public static void dumphash(){
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         LinkedList list = array[i];
         System.out.println(i + ":" + list.dumplist());
      }    
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
      initArray();
      insert(1);
      insert(5);
      insert(28);
      delete(5);
      insert(15);
      insert(8);
      dumphash();
      delete(1);
      insert(18);
      insert(25);
      delete(33);
      dumphash();
   }
}

////////////////////////////

public class LinkedList{
   static Node head;

   public LinkedList() {
      head = null;
   }

   public void insertData(int data){
      Node node = new Node();
      node.data = data;
      node.next = null;

      if(head == null){
         head = node;
      }
      else{
         Node n = head;
         while(n.next != null){
            n = n.next;
         }
         n.next = node;
         node.setValue(data);
      }
   }

   public static void remove(int data){
      Node node = head;
      boolean removed = false;
      if(node.getValue() == data){
         Node temp = head;
         head = head.next;
         temp.next = null;
         System.out.println(data + " has been removed.");
         removed = true;
      }
      else{
         while(node.next != null){
            if(node.next.getValue() == data){
               node.next = node.next.next;
               System.out.println(data + " has been removed.");
               removed = true;
            }
            else{
               node = node.next;
               if(node.next == null && removed == false){
                  System.out.println("Error: " + data + " has not been inserted.");
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public static String dumplist(){
      String fullList = "";
      Node node = head;
      if(node.getValue() == null){
         fullList = " Empty.";
      }
      else{
         while(node.next != null){
            fullList = fullList + " " + node.data;
            node = node.next;
         }
         fullList = fullList + " " + node.data;
      }
     return fullList;
   }
}

////////////////////////////

public class Node{
   int data;
   Node next;

   public Integer getValue(){
      return  data;
  }

   public void setValue(int val){
     this.data = val;
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you've declared all your member variables `static`; that means you have just one instance per class rather than one per object. So all of your `LinkedList` instances point to the very same `Node` as the `head`. You should not need `static` here at all except for the `main` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I remove static from each method I get a "error: non-static method *insert method here* cannot be referenced from a static context" for every line within the main. How should I go about fixing that?

Comment: You have to have an instance of an object to call non-static methods on it, e.g. `Foo f = new Foo(); f.doStuff();`

Comment: Just a heads up, you will get a null pointer exception in your linked list implementation